# LaTeX to Word converter

Tags: conversion, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

What ways can you convert a LaTeX file to a Word document?

What resources/articles exist to help get this done?

Comment: @Szymon, two pointers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-can-i-convert-math-less-latex-documents-into-microsoft-word, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format

Comment: @Szymon: Welcome to TeX.SX. You LaTeX question was migrated here (first to our meta site by mistake). This topic was already discussed by some questions (see links) so I closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Martin... I didn't even know about TeX.SX :)

Answer (score 18):

Use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to "export" the LaTeX file to a format that is readable by Word.

One way would be to use pandoc for LaTeX to RTF, then open the RTF in word, and use "save as" to get it into the final state.  Word doesn't have the same kind of support for complex layouts, beautiful typography, etc. that LaTeX does, so the layout will not likely render the same; you might have to re-format parts of the page going into Word.

The basic command to do this is:

```
pandoc -s INPUT.tex -o OUTPUT.rtf
```

I'm not sure how it'll render the RTF, depending on your layouts, etc. so their may be a more suitable output type than RTF, depending on what filetypes Word supports, and the nature of your LaTeX.

Pandoc can output to plain text, markdown, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, ConTeXt, PDF, RTF, DocBook XML, OpenDocument XML, ODT, GNU Texinfo, MediaWiki markup, textile, groff man pages, Emacs org-mode, EPUB ebooks, and S5 and Slidy HTML slide shows.

You can also experiment with pandoc using its [online demo](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try), though that won't support any LaTeX extensions you might be using.

The key is finding a filetype that will render well, and then seeing how it looks when opened in Word; some experimentation will be needed.

Comment: Thanks, for getting a basic output for simply annotating, this was very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not export my bibliography. Does anyone know a solution for this?