# How to automatically (semi, if not fully) convert two-column LaTeX paper into MS-Word

Tags: two-column, msword

I could not find full automatic conversion with math formulas and figures. Thought, let me get converted to ASCII then I will paste and format. Even that did not work well due to two-columns. I had to manually select-and-paste pdf, re-do all the maths and insert figures.

Any better way?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of existing questions in the "related" list  eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13927/latex-to-word-converter?rq=1 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format or specifically on math: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word/115065#115065

Comment: There really is no good way. You could deal with the two column issue by recompiling the TeX in single column (unless all you have is the pdf). Searching this site for "convert tex to word" will lead you to some useful information.

Comment: `tex4ht` can deal with simple formatting and maths but it turns the maths into something in a sort of frame with anchors. (No idea - maybe that's how Word usually does maths?) At least, you can produce `odt` this way and then export to `doc` or `docx` from LibreOffice.