# How do I export LaTeX generated formulas to other documents besides PDFs such as MS-Word?

Tags: math-mode, conversion, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word)

What I ultimately want to do is take the formulas I made, and use them anywhere, like copy/pasting them into MS-Word, or into Excel, or PowerPoint, or whatever else. (This was what I was trying to do originally).

The problem is if I copy/paste from the PDF I made, it will not show up on MS-Word, or it shows up in weird characters. So I was thinking along the lines of an image or something.

Either way I don't care how its done, but I would like to grab the nice formulations I generate with MiKTeX, and paste them into documents I have, how can this be done?

Comment: What about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format

Comment: Please search our question database before asking a new question. A lot of (if not most) typical beginner questions have already been asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instal LaTeXit ([Laeqed](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php)) . You copy your equation (from your .tex file, I mean latex source of your equation) into the editor from where you can export your equation as an image (.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but from the site it seems this is for Apple only? I have windows machine unfortunately.

Comment: @Mohammad Pl. visit http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/. There you have it for windows. FYI, I also use windows.