# Is there an equation editor for Windows?

Tags: math-mode, windows

Is there anything like [LaTeXit](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php), a Mac-only program, that converts math equations into LaTeX code, for windows?

Comment: You might be interested in answers here, though not specific to what you ask: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word

Answer (score 10):

[This list](http://alternativeto.net/software/latexit/?platform=windows) might be a good place to start.  The third item on the list, [KLatexFormula](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net/), looks promising.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Just installed KLatexFormula and it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The pain in the ass for `kLatexFormula` is the `drag'n'drop` function does not work for many programmes, like Adobe Illustrator, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Latex Equation editor](http://latexeqedit.sourceforge.net/) and [Laeqed](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/).

Comment: Can't Latex Equation Editor to work. Keeps throwing unintelligible errors even though I pointed it at the files it wanted.

Comment: Same for me, also I couldn't find any solution...

Comment: I got the same error with Latex Equation editor.  It could be a 32bit vs. 64bit issue.  Latex Equation editor did not specify which version to download.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [EqualX](http://equalx.sourceforge.net/). It seems to work very well. The only bad thing is you can drag and drop, you need to copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome, there is an extension that LaTeXifies https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dinfmiceliiomokeofbocegmacmagjhe

Update:
Daum editor requires Adobe Flash which is no longer supported by Chrome and Edge is also phasing out.

Answer (score 0):

the best Windows editor for LaTeX/Tex is [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/Download)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I wouldn't actually call LyX a LaTeX editor. It has it's own file format, and while it does use LaTeX in the background, you don't really have complete control of the code being created by LyX.

Comment: Thanks,True enough.  It really is a word processor/editor.  However, all the LateX/TeX code is editable if all you want to do is write documents.  How about Mathjax?  I've never used it, but it does seem to be able to edit TeX source.

Comment: For the main body yes, but not so for the preamble. MathJaX is a JavaScript library for rendering math in web browsers, and can understand some LaTeX syntax, but only stuff related to math, AFAIK.

Comment: LaTeXit is very different from LyX; its purpose is to compile code snippets producing a PDF that can be pasted in another program.

Comment: LyX inserts all kinds of special stuff into the latex it generates. It's essentially a separate format. Once something has been edited in LyX, you have to do a lot of work to make it function elsewhere. SO while LyX itself is great, it is not truly cross compatible like latex.

Comment: I strongly disagree with Elliot. LyX is a document processor but nearly a  WYSYWYG editor for the math part that produce a *very clean* LaTeX code, perfectly compilable in any LaTeX editor . Its purpose is not only  produce code snippets for equations but it can be used for this, in real time, with the source pane. You only have to take care that math commands as  `\geqslant` will also add a package in the preamble (`amssymb`` in this case)  and obviously the equation snippet pasted  alone will not work in a document with an empty preamble.