# Is there an easier way to type math symbols than adding them with LaTex?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to add math symbols to my texts, but i can't get Latex to work, are there other ways to type math symbols?

Comment: It might seem tempting to stay away from LaTeX as it requires some time to learn, but if you are going to make a lot of documents with math in them I strongly would suggest learning LaTeX. You will save a lot of time in the long run, especially if you want to type more advanced math.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). This question is not very clear. What is the problem you had with LaTeX? Saying it does not work does not really provide any information that can be used to diagnose the problem. Are you having a problem just with math symbols? Can you even get a basic document without any math to compile with LaTeX? For example does thsi compile for you: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}`?  Where do you want to type these math symbols?

Comment: Downvoted because this topic doesn't provide any information. I suggest deletion. Furthermore, I would advise getting a book about LaTeX, for example Kopka's "Guide to LaTeX", or using Google to find one of the abundant tutorials online. It really is not hard to get started if one shows a modicum of effort.

Comment: @mSSM On the other hand, Daniel has 1 reputation and this is his first question ever on the whole StackExchange. We prefer not to downvote in such situtaion. It is better to motivate newcomers to improve their question than to punish them by downvotes.

Comment: And to the close-voter: please, leave some time for Daniel to explain his question before it gets closed. This is the standard attitude on TeX.SX!

Comment: @tohecz One day passed, no further explanations. I think this question should be deleted.

Comment: Possibly Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52741/is-there-an-equation-editor-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

There are online tables for symbols that you can use to add math symbols, just copy and past from them into your documents.There is also this [keyboard for writing math symbols and equations](http://www.mathkeyboard.com/).

Comment: You might want to add that using those symbols directly in LaTeX might require the use of `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, as those keys are usually display UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this online latex compiler (this one is specially thought for equations):
 http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

You can download the images for your equations from there and then add them to your
texts.