# How to use "LaTeX in Word"?

Tags: msword

I need help using [LaTeX in Word](http://latexinword.sourceforge.net/). This SourceForge project seems fabulous but I do not know how to use it. According to the guide,

```
To enter an inline equation, simply move the cursor to the point where you would 
like to insert the equation and type alt-l. This will bring-up the LaTeX Entry GUI.
```

I try typing `ALT-L` in lower case and no GUI shows up. Also, it would be great if someone can show me how to setup the server on my own computer. Apparently, the lack of documentations is the sore of this project.

Comment: "it would be great if someone can show me how to setup the server on my own computer" ... I probably can't help you, since I haven't used Windows for years, but if others are to help you, I think you need to clearify what you mean. Personally, I have no clue. (Btw., [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).)

Comment: This badly documented project uses php and perl to interface with LaTeX and run a script to run a server (defaults to an online link) to generate .png images for equations. To set your own server use WAMP. Not too sure if this is the best approach for you to type your maths though.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Is it possible to change the server to MathJax?

Comment: @KevinC I think it will be difficult as MathJax is primarily aiming at web pages.

Comment: What about switching completly to LaTeX? If you already TeXify your math, then TeXifiyng your text, too, will be a piece of cake.

Comment: The newer versions of MS Word can handle some LaTeX syntax in math mode.

Comment: There are other LaTeX plugins for Word. Check [Aurora](http://elevatorlady.ca/index.html) which has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Microsoft Word 2016 is supposed to have an update that allows some LaTeX to be entered into the equation editor. This may be an answer in the future. I have tried this several times using Build 16.0.8432.2046 but this does not seem to be work as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not averse to using LibreOffice/OpenOffice, I would suggest [TexMaths](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/). I have used it under Writer and Impress and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened the word document `LaTeXinWord_03_v_0_3_1.doc` ? This is in fact all you need!

That document has the macros contained in it. If you click on an equation in this document, and press `ALT+L`, it should show the GUI. If this doesn't work, then sorry I can't help.

If it says "Macros are disabled", then you need to set security to medium. I am using Word 2003, so I went to `Tools/Macro/Security` --> Medium --> OK, then close and re-open the document. It should ask "Enable Macros?" --> Yes.

For me, it worked out-of-the box without installing any of the server code. Looking at the script, by default it uses the server at `web.ics.purdue.edu/~ntoner/Process_LaTeX/`. Which is great!

The simplest solution is to save `LaTeXinWord` doc file as a template (.dot). Then you have to either create new documents based on that template, or add the template in using `Options/Templates and add-ins/Add`.

If you want to use it in your own document, you obviously have to go to `Tools/Templates and add-ins/Organizer.../Macro Project Items`, select the 4 macro's from the left hand side `EqnBookmark`, `LaTeX_Entry`, `LaTeXMacros` and `Report_Error`, load the destination document on the right hand side (`Close File/Open File...`) and copy the 4 macros across to the document you want to use them in. You can copy them to a normal Word doc, or to a template e.g. `Normal.dot` -- if you do the latter, then you can use the macros in any new documents you create. Note that if you want to use LaTeX in any old Word documents you already have, you have to manually copy the macros across, as described.

Note that in this case, you will need to re-assign the keyboard shortcuts. To do this in Word 2003, go to `Tools/Customize/Keyboard`, select `Categories:Macros`, and select your document with the macros in it under `Save changes in`, then select `Macros:LaTeXEntry`, and press `Alt+L` in the "new shortcut key", then `Assign`, `Close`.

--

### 2016 Update for newer versions of Word

1. Open the `LatxInWord.docm` word document. Macros must be enabled. Press `Enable editing` in the yellow warning bar, then `Enable Content` in the next yellow warning bar, then `View / Edit document`.
2. Select `File menu / Options / Add-ins`
3. At the bottom in the drop-down `Manage` menu, select `Templates` and press `Go...`
4. At the bottom left click `Organizer...`, then select the `Macro project items` tab.
5. Select the four macros in the LatexInWord document, then `Copy ->` to `Normal.dotm`. For me, these two files were open by default in the left and right panels, respectively.
6. To set up keyboard shortcuts, `File / Options / Customize Ribbon / Customize Keyboard`
7. Select `Macros` on left, near bottom of `Categories` list, then `LaTeXEntry` from the `Macros` list on the right.
8. Choose keyboard shortcut eg `Alt+L` and `Assign` and `Close`.