# How to use Latex in MS Word

Tags: installing, msword

I downloaded latex in word from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/latexinword/

But it just gives me an archive file that I have no idea what to do with. And I can't see any installation instructions anywhere either.

Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: I just read the `readme` ... well, this seems to really complicated, as it requires you to have access to a unix/linux based 'server' with some tools (LaTeX, perl, php etc.) installed and a client-side VBA macros to use LaTeX inside Word. Since I do not use Windows/Word at all, I can not give any recommendations

Comment: Well all I know is that some assignments I have want me to use Latex so the math is neat but I don't know what is meant by "use" Latex

Comment: Do you know the basics of LaTeX at all? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "LaTeX in Word"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111130/how-to-use-latex-in-word)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running certain macros under MS Word, rather than about TeX or LaTeX itself.

Comment: I saw a fried using this and it seem to suck slightly less: http://thd.pnpi.spb.ru/~gromov/mytexpoint.html (also particularly better in PowerPoint than in Word).

Comment: The most straightforward way to 'use LaTeX' is to use LaTeX i.e. to use a proper editor to produce your document rather than messing around with an application which is far from designed for anything like this. If you don't want to learn much LaTeX and you do not need to, you could try Lyx. I think that is likely to be a more fruitful path than trying to fit LaTeX into Word. (There's a similar set up you can use for LibreOffice but, again, I don't really see the point.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I suspect mentioning MS Word might get you banned for life on TeX.SX, this looks like an interesting feature.

It appears to be a Macro, so review this perhaps: [Record or Run a Macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/record-or-run-a-macro-HA010099769.aspx)

And after reading this review by this guy who shows as one of the developers, [mrsparkle713](http://sourceforge.net/users/mrsparkle713), I think it might help to contact one of them.

> This is an easy plugin for LaTeX in Word. One very nice feature is
>   that it does not require you to install anything on your computer. It
>   all runs out of Word using macros, and the LaTeX conversion is done on
>   a remote server that can be changed if you don't want to use the one
>   that is set up. Now that I have this I need to really learn LaTeX.
>   After the learning curve, it should be a lot easier and more
>   convenient to use than the equation editor that Word provides. I will
>   be maintaining the project shortly, so take my review with a grain of
>   salt.

Comment: Interesting feature it might be, but why would I write a document in Word and insert the math written in LaTeX. If I have to take the time to learn LaTeX to write the math, like the developer says, why would I bother going back to Word to write the text, when LaTeX will give me a - I won't even say a better one - just a more cohesive visual appearance between text and math. I fail to see the advantage of mixing the two. If it is only a bit of math, Word 2013 provides a math editor that manages to understand \lambda^2 and the like.