# How to embed LaTeX symbols in excel sheets

Tags: excel2latex, exceltex

I would like to embed LaTeX symbols into Excel worksheets. This basically means each cell entry needs to display equations for example. I know there is a indirect but inconvenient solution of using [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) to transform excel tables into LaTeX. But this beats the advantage of having the symbols in the excel sheet, and sorting and manipulating the symbol with other numbers, names and other attributes. Are there any simple workarounds available?

I have also looked at [IguanaTex](http://tx.technion.ac.il/~zvikabh/software/iguanatex/) but this is only a Powerpoint addin.
There are a group of free LaTeX tools available for [Microsoft office](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word) but there is no indication on whether they support Excel. Maybe I am wrong here, but needs clarification.

Comment: You should use Unicode characters, which you can then use as-is in LaTeX.

Comment: Unicode characters work fine when using XeLaTeX + the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Doesn't the newest edition of Excel have the new Equation Editor?

Comment: Thx for the workarounds! A free latex solution embedded in Excel would be preferable. I know there are other ways to achieve this outside latex. Edit: The other solution again indirect i found is [using images in excel cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Excel and what it is capable of, not actually about TeX.

Comment: Well it is tagged for excel2latex, and involves latex and their interaction. I guess i am going to use the equations directly in latex and then change to tables. This is still suboptimal and would lose capabilities of excel.