# Generate external images for all equations in a document

Tags: equations, conversion

I have to convert a LaTeX document to a Microsoft Word template due to circumstances I cannot alter (intergovernmental organisation).  With `\tikzexternalize`, I can easily generate images for all my graphics, that I can then include in the Word document.  Is there a similar way to convert all *equations* into external images?  I find that would be an easier (and prettier) way to go, than to convert LaTeX-equations to Microsoft Office equations.

I know there are other ways to convert equations, such as the ones listed at *[Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25223/8141)*, but I wonder if the path I'm thinking of is possible.  Moreover, wanting images may have other applications, such as inclusion on websites (when no MathML is available) or so.

I have ten equations in total, so a solution adding code to the LaTeX source is acceptable.

Comment: Immediately voting to close my own question as a duplicate — only after writing the full question did Stack Exchange suggest a similar question containing the answer, but this 'path' may still be useful for future answer-seekers.