# Is it possible to get EPS output from XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, eps

I need to get a good way to produce quality equations in MS Word documents. There is no simple way to produce vector graphics in TeX, that Word natively understands (`EMF`, `WMF`). There is yet another vector graphics format that Word kind of supports: `EPS`. I could automate generation of equations in `EPS` format, adding a preview bitmap and inserting it into Word, just like [SWord](http://sourceforge.net/p/texsword/wiki/Home/) does.

And now I have a question: how to get the XeLaTeX to produce `EPS` output?

I know, that a long time ago, the legacy LaTeX could do that, but I'd prefer not to hang to it if I could.

Comment: More info on the problem on: http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=980

Comment: convertion between eps and EPS is usually lossless they are the same underlying (adobe postscript) rendering model, so you can use any pdf to eps convertor. But to be honest Word's math rendering (post 2007) isn't bad, and you'll get a lot more consistent appearance if you let it render it. (you could for example convert the math to MathML and then cut and paste it into word as editable text)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is a very good idea. I'll see into it.

Comment: I' d suggest caution in saying Word 'supports EPS'. Older versions of Word will use a (low res) bitmap preview of the EPS but do save the 'real' thing inside the Word file. Newer versions don't even do that: imported EPS files are converted to bitmap format. I find its better to convert using another tool (IrfanView/GhostScript) and paste in that way, as I can then control the resolution.

Comment: see this answer for tex->mathjax->MathML->Word http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word/115065#115065