# The easiest way to write TeX in MS Word?

Tags: msword

Is there some way I can use MS Word with the TeX formulas? On [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) I've learned the syntax `$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$` etc.. But I do not know how to create a LaTeX document. Is there some way I can use this syntax in MS Word?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). About your question, well there are software that you can use for convert word documents into tex files. I remember the last versions of [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/default.htm)  are compatible with LaTeX. I don't know, I try to don't use it, but if you want, you can try it.

Comment: @Aradnix Thank you very much. My problem is that I do not have too much time to learn Latex programming, is there a very fast and easy way to do it?

Comment: A fast and easy way to do what?

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115065/12440

Comment: Actually, most of the LaTeX commands are supported in the Word built-in equation editor (built-in since Office 2007), such as `\delta` and similar for the Greek letters, `\partial` for the partial derivative symbol, `\approx` for "approximately equal to", etc. To get the "conversion" to happen, simply push the spacebar after you're finished typing. Notably, the `\frac` command is not supported, but you can simply type, e.g. `(x+1)/3` and push space and Word will format as though it were in a display math `\frac`

Comment: Investing one day to learn basic LaTeX pays off very fast once you are struggling with Word.

Comment: @Aradnix learn latex programming.

Comment: @user62268 In my own experience the best way to learn LaTeX is reading and making your own documents in LaTeX. Learning how to achieve what you want and from your errors. Ten years ago I started with a [old book](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english) and MikTeX. Now there is a lot of facilities, including sites like [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) or [ShareLaTeX](https://es.sharelatex.com/) in the cloud where you can start without install anything. We all have 24 hours a day, depends on us how we use them, is the same thought that Uwe remarked.