# Problems with latex in word 2010

Tags: errors, windows

I`m trying to insert LaTex into Word 2010.

I`m following the method that the user David Carlisle described here in an answer:

[Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word)

I`m trying the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<title>tex texample</title>
</head>
<body>
$$\left \lfloor{\frac{S}{2}}\right \rfloor \times 4  + \frac{N \times 4}{2} +4  $$
</body>
</html>
```

It works on the browser

[image: formula]

Then i get the MathMl code as described in his post and i added the line  at the beginning as he said in his post and i have this code:

[image: Math ML]

But when i post it to word, it appears like this:

[image: bad formula]

What can i do to make the formula appear the same in word as in the browser?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

These are the equation options in my word, they are written in spanish.

[image: Options]

Well, i finally made it work, i pasted the equation in a word that was completely empty and it appeared well

[image: picture 2]

Then i copied the formula and pasted it in the other word that wasn`t empty and it worked

[image: picture 3]

I seems that you have to paste the html file on an empty word to make it work. And then you can paste the formula to another word that isn`t empty. Seems that you cant paste it to a word with things written on it directly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This rather looks like a MathJaX question than a true LaTeX question

Comment: @ChristianHupfer in the referenced question I just suggested mathjax as being a convenient latex-math to mathml convertor so I think it's as on topic as tex4ht or latexml questions, it isn't  asking about specific mathjax features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have word2010 and it worked for me:

[image]

In case it makes any difference these are the settings in my math tools settings thing (I think they are the default, I never use Word)

[image]

Comment: where are the equation options?, i dont find them in my word

Comment: @rotia not surprising: word's "ribbon" interface is not exactly intuitive:-)  if you type alt= it wil start a new math zone click on there and the equation bar thing appears then under the big Pi sign it says `tools` and next to that is a tiny button with a diagonal arrow click on that and the above menu appears.

Comment: I found the options, seem to be the same than yours

Comment: @rotia looks like it. I really never use Word so it is hard for me to guess. I have windows 8 64 (English) and Word 2010 and pretty much default settings for both, for me it "just worked" (and checking that it works when a new version comes out is all I ever use word for, apart from the occasional document I get sent) sorry I can't help more. You could try some other editor than notepad (anything) to see if it puts the information on the clipboard in a different format that word does recognise.

Comment: @rotia wow that's weird. but then Word is strange. Anyway glad you got it working, even if the route is even longer than I described.