# Problems when embedding LaTeX \dot and \hat into Microsoft Word thru MathML

Tags: msword, mathml, latex-to-word

From the post [Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word/115065#115065) , I know \dot{z} in LaTeX can be translated in MathML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
    <mover>
      <mi>z</mi>
      <mo>&#x02D9;<!-- ˙ --></mo>
    </mover>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

However, when I pasted the code above into Microsoft Word, I got a dot far away from the letter z (shown on the left in the image below), which looks quite inappropriate compared to the result I got from typing "\dot{z}" directly in Word (shown on the right). Similar problems occur for \hat and \ddot.

[image]

When embedding LaTeX equations that include \dot and \hat into Word, is there a way to render the result better, i.e., to put the dot or hat closer to the letter?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic for this site. You need to ask on a site concerned with MS Word and this really isn't the place. Mathml isn't LaTeX. The equations aren't LaTeX once they're translated that way and the problem you're seeing doesn't have anything to do with TeX.

Comment: Conversion is on-topic, but I'm taking it this is a problem in Word's or MathJax's rendering/conversion, rather than with the conversion process on the TeX side. You could look at the mathml Word's using and compare. Then you might be able to figure out a way to adapt the results of the cut-paste.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Maybe I can try stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: I think you might be more likely to get a useful answer there. The linked question shows people do use/know Word and one of them is David Carlisle, but it isn't really a TeX issue and I think the number of people who might 'happen to know' here will inevitably be smaller than you'd find elsewhere.

Comment: I got a useful answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764838/4467902