# How do I write formulas in Microsoft Word using LaTex

Tags: formatting

I would like to write formulas in word using LaTex, but I don't know how.

I am new to LaTex.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "write formulas in Word using LaTeX".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word)

Comment: It is possible (but error prone and tricky) to convert latex math to Word, but it is not something you would want to do regularly just a one-off if forced to convert a latex document to Word.  Word does have a "latex style" for its linear input form for math but it is not really very much like latex at all, just allows a few extra `\ ` and `{}` than its normal linear math syntax, to make it look a little bit like tex in simple cases.