# How to format amsmath correctly in MS word?

Tags: amsmath, lyx, msword, latex-to-word

I've been working on a math report by writing down all my formulae in LyX (because it was easier). I am able to export it to MS word, but it's difficult to edit the equations, especially in word (because I can't continuously make changes in lyx and export every time). So is there some way I can get MS Word to properly interpret amsmath latex code?

Comment: The right question to me is that if you are already using LyX successfully for math formulas ... why the hell you are not making the whole report in LyX? Even if you need to pass a Word version to someone, it is easier to make the whole document in LyX and export just once (only the final version).

Comment: A. I'm not too familiar with LyX, and trying to align text and images like I could in word seems a little tricky. B. I don't have the time right now to learn LyX completely. C. All our reports have to be sent to our teachers in MS Word

Comment: Align text other that justify (default) is just select text → right click → Paragraph... On the other hand, the images placement, imho,  is one major reason to switch from Word to LyX/LaTeX. You only have to understand that image (Insert → Graphics) ≠ figure (Insert → Float → Figure). The figures are float objects (jump to a presumible best place, if possible),  while the images are non floats objects (= same placement that any big character) except inside a float.  But you can always control how the float is floating with right click (in the float label) → Setting ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! As much as I would like to switch, I don't have the time right now. Also our school always uses word documents for reports. So I just want to find a quick fix.

Comment: Take your time to understand well [how a float  work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/),  and that a figure floating a bit  never hurt if you insert a label in caption,  and a cross-reference in text  (both via `Insert` menu or toolbar buttons),  and you will not regret.

Comment: Respect to the "quick fix"  (that IMHO is the wrong solution) seems a duplicate of  [Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word)

Comment: @Fran I gave up on word and just used LyX. It took a while for me to get the hang of it, but it was much better compared to word's dreadful latex implementation. Thanks a lot!