# Converting LaTeX to Word?

Tags: msword

I am new to LaTeX and was wondering whether anyone knew how to apply the conversion. I've attached the following code as a reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{Rules}
\author{Mohamed Mirza}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Essentials}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are aspirin and razor blades a permissible part of the answer?  Just kidding!  Welcome to the site!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online/1654#1654, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-can-i-convert-math-less-latex-documents-into-microsoft-word, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format/41306#41306.  The search feature of this site is quite good.