# Convverting pdf file given by latex to word

Tags: latex-to-word

My supervisor told me that for revised version we need to have the word file. However, I dont know how to do that. If I use grindeq then the figures are missed. Also, when I change pdf to word in any software it is not ideal and there are some inconsistency. Any idea?

Comment: some online converters can do it somehow accurately... I don't know which right now... I just wanted to say to disable hyphens before the conversion and possibly no headers/footers and page numbers too (for better results)... Add them through word

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124168/161015

Comment: Do you only have the PDF, or do you have the LaTeX source? If you really must convert a PDF, [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/)'s `ebook-convert` or [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/)'s `pdftohtml` (Word can import HTML) are the best free software solutions I've tried, but I doubt they'll do very well with equations either. If you have the source, then try both [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) (to odt format which Word can open), or as a last resort, [latex2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) (again Word can read rtf).

Comment: How large is the Word document, in terms of pages, number of drawings, tables etc.? Many times the fastest way is doing it manually, i.e. obtaining plain-ASCII first, assigning formats etc.

Comment: @frabjous I have both

Comment: can you please let me know how to use latex2rtf after download it?! I could not find the latex2rtf-x.x.x_win.exe

Comment: I use linux and get the binaries from my distro's package manager. I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment, but it looks like the sourceforge page only distributes the source code. There's a `winmake.bat` batch file in the tarball that I would *guess* compiles the code to create the .exe file on Windows, but of course you'd need a C compiler. Also see the `README.DOS` file. But it looks like the binary is [available on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latex2rtf) as well.

Comment: There are some other options mentioned on the [TeX FAQ page on converting](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fmtconv) between formats as well.